# I can not log in with the user created on the server

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to make a mobile profile in Windows Server 2016, I created the user account on Active Directory Users and Computers and i set the path to profile like this: http://prntscr.com/hg8joh

Now I am trying to log in with that user account from a Windows 10 client but it shows the following error:

> The security database on the server does not have a computer account
>   for the trust relationship of this station.

I can log in with the admin account and the both computers can do ping to each other so I do not know what to do. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLVED POST

I think I just needed to put the Server IP on the Preferred DNS server on the client computer so now it's solved :D